# Тестирование клиента с получением данных через graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql

Как грамотно тестировать приложение с graphql клиентом? Раньше я инкапсулировал логику получения данных в классах и определял их объекты, в зависимости от сборки, в Provider, которыми оборачивал остальное приложение.

Сейчас же получается так, что для того чтобы тестировать graphql клиента мне видимо нужно поднимать какой нибудь дефолтный сервер и описывать его логику отдачи данных. Это так или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Да, в случае с graphql пишутся интеграционные тесты, то есть необходимо развернуть тестовое окружение для graphql и дергать запросы к нему и проверять данные, полученные из него. Причем это тестовое окружение должно иметь некий набор тестовых данных, и эти данные должны быть описаны в качестве ожидаемых, в интеграционных тестах. В интеграционных тестах как минимум затянуть `graphql-tag` и `axios` пакеты, чтобы дергать graphql запросы.